# What is the pattern to show closely coupled data?

Tags: design-patterns

Like tab structure is used for showing not closely coupled data. Is there a pattern to show tightly coupled data.

For Example:

I have a record of a person with following categories.

1: Personal/official information

2: Audit information of his record

3: Related data from social media.

4: Relationship among other records presented in the system.(like if I'm viewing records of a person who has 2 sons and wife, under relationship category I will get brief info about his family members.

Please Note: I can't show data in a single page with categories as a heading, because there would be huge-huge data per category. In existing system we are showing categories in the form of tabs. And Tabs are not meant for that as per the pattern libraries.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do you have any evidences of issues with tabs?
2. See the tab-like example of the coupled data (youtube). The animation is used to convey the closiness of the categories for the entity:

   [image]

Comment: I can't post any example here, will post later.But as stated in pattern libraries, tab must be used for loosely coupled data only. Also, about, share and add to are  child of a parent category(video). In my case I don't have any parent category. I've 4 closely coupled categories.

Comment: @Hem 1) Don't treat design patterns as dogma. 2) Looseness or tightness of the data is subjective. 3) You have Person as entity and categories related to it. 4) For best results base your decisions on objective metrics which could be collected during research (usability testing, A/B testing, etc.)/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have is the space on the screen. You can have a single page with sections and have scrollable area for the sections.

I don't think the Person Information, Audit information & Related information are categories. They are all related to Person like order or product details which can contain the price information, inventory information, related products etc...